# npm run electron:serve command stuck at 40%

Tags: vue.js, electron, vue-router

Hi there hope y'all doing well. I'm using vutify with vue-router and electronjs, I'm working with v-list components in vutify everything was working well But somehow when i ran the serve command the compiler gets stuck at 40%:

```
PS C:\electronjs\mohammediatech> npm run electron:serve

> mohammediatech@0.1.0 electron:serve
> vue-cli-service electron:serve

 INFO  Starting development server...
40% building 157/172 modules 15 active C:\Electronjs\mohammediatech\node_modules\html-entities\lib\html5-entities.js
```

Router/index.js :

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'

Vue.use(VueRouter)

import dashboard from'../components/dashboard.vue'
import clients from'../components/clients.vue'
import suppliers from'../components/suppliers.vue'
import products from'../components/products.vue'
import invoices from'../components/invoices.vue'

const routes= [
    {
        component: dashboard,
        name:dashboard,
        path:'/'
    },
    {
        component: suppliers,
        name:suppliers,
        path:'/suppliers'
    },
    {
        component: products,
        name:products,
        path:'/products'
    },
    {
        component: clients,
        name:clients,
        path:'/clients'
    },
    {
        component: invoices,
        name:invoices,
        path:'/invoices'
    },
];

export default new VueRouter({
    routes,
    mode:'history'

})
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solved !** I ran  `npm run lint` to check if there's any problems with the code in any of the components then i found out that i was only putting plain text inside the template tag like this any many components:

```
<template >
Products
</template>
```

I added a div to wrap the text, recompiled and it Worked!